# How to force user to open my website in safari when they access my wordpress site

Tags: php, ios, wordpress, facebook

My website has Facebook log in function, which does not work if user views my site on facebook app, messenger app, iOS chrome app, Gmail app of iPhone.

Therefore, I need to force user to open site on Safari in such case.

Is there any way to do that? My site is built by wordpress.
Thanks!

UPDATE 1: I am thinking about a javascript to detect if users is on iOS, then pop up a javascript to ask if user wants to view on safari. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an Apple app like Mail, Messages, Notes etc. It will open with Safari, but if you are in another app eg. Facebook, Twitter, anything developed by a developer, you can't choose how you want to handle URLs in their app, that is up to the developer, and as a developer and Apple guidelines, it is best to open URLs in app so that the user don't leave your app. They use Safari anyway as UIWebView is a component of Safari, and we use UIWebView to browse inside our apps. *(This can be manipulated, but still doesn't change the answer as to where you can't control how to handle links inside apps.)*

Comment: my website is just a normal wordpress website. I dont know what you mean by "if you are loading your website from a UIWebView"

Comment: you tagged iOS, so I assume you want to open a certain URL from you iPhone, correct? What am I missing?

Comment: No, Let's say there is an email, facebook post with an url "http://www.mywebsite.com". When user click on that url, I want user to be forced to open in safari, not iphone app, messenger app, gmail app.

Comment: Have a read here: http://blog.mobtest.com/2012/05/heres-why-the-facebook-ios-app-is-so-bad-uiwebviews-and-no-nitro/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to open a specific browser (Safari in your case) from a website.

If you're working on an app, you might want to have a look at `SFSafariViewController`.

Have a brief idea about different kind of webviews in iOS [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-getting-started-with-sfsafariviewcontroller--cms-24260)